# SQL Server full-text search, which column should I choose between two candidate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

In my classified ad site, two columns are candidates for full text search, one `Ad_Title` and the second one is `Ad_Description`. Which one I should use to implement full text search, speaking in terms of visitors who would search ads with their own requirements?

My current feature provides two types of searches, one is generic/simple search and the other one is advanced search. In my view simple search should rely on `Ad_Title` while the advanced search feature should work with `Ad_Description`.

Also I would like to mention that my `Ad_Title` column is of data type `varchar(150)` and `Ad_Description` column is `varchar(Max)` (which I restricted to 600 by front end validation). Please provide me some suggestion.

Comment: Another suggestion: if you have limited `Ad_description` to 600 characters in your front end - then ***please*** use `varchar(600)` in your database table (instead of `varchar(max)`) !

Comment: Yes Marc, i know i should do it, but not now. there some dependencies which currently hurdle in my way, i am planning to remove these at the end. till then i will still work with my current setting.